# In what order to add .gitignore and other files?

Tags: git

Should I create my .gitignore file first, and then do:

```
git init .
git add .
```

I did :

```
git init .
git add .gitignore
git add .
```

And I found it didn't ignore the folders / files in my gitignore file.
The .gitignore file has been created correctly because it is used as part of a large open source project, and hasn't been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already track all the file, folder in the repository then add gitignore that's why it's not working.

To fix this, first you have to untrack those file/folder with this command:

```
git rm -r --cached folder_name/file
```

then git add, git commit those new changes.